# How to add for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm creating new files from originally existing ones in the mdp folder by changing a couple of lines in those files using python. I need to do this for 1000 files. Can anyone suggest a for loop which reads all files and changes them and creates new in one go?

This way I have to change the the number followed by 'md_' in the path and it's tedious because there are a 1000 files here.

I tried using str() but there was a 'could not read file error'

```
fin = open("/home/abc/xyz/mdp/md_1.mdp", "rt") 
fout = open("/home/abc/xyz/middle/md_1.mdp", "wt")

for line in fin:
fout.write(line.replace('integrator               = md', 'integrator    
= md-vv'))
fin = open("/home/abc/xyz/middle/md_1.mdp", "rt")
fout = open("/home/abc/xyz/mdb/md_1.mdp", "wt")

for line in fin:
fout.write(line.replace('dt                       = 0.001', 'dt                       
= -0.001'))

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried so we can better evaluate what is going wrong, rather than guessing what you may have written.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation - and by all means, learn to properly close your files.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts, I have written my code that I tried. This works when I'm trying to make changes in one file at a time. I have 1000 such files and I want to know how it'd work in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir(path)` is your friend:

```
import os

sourcedir = "/home/abc/xyz/mdp"
destdir = "/home/abc/xyz/middle"

for filename in os.listdir(sourcedir):
    if not filename.endswith(".mdp"):
        continue

    source = os.path.join(sourcedir, filename)
    dest = os.path.join(destdir, filename)

    # with open(xxx) as varname makes sure the file(s)
    # will be closed whatever happens in the 'with' block
    # NB text mode is the default, and so is read mode
    with open(source) as fin, open(dest, "w") as fout:
        # python files are iterable... avoids reading
        # the whole file in memory at once
        for line in fin:
            # will only work for those exact strings,
            # you may want to use regexps if number of
            # whitespaces vary etc
            line = line.replace("dt = 0.001", "dt = -0.001")
            line = line.replace(
                'integrator               = md',
                'integrator    = md-vv'
                )
            fout.write(line)
```

Comment: I tried this but it says:
dest.write(line)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: There's a typo indeed, should have been `fout.write()` of course - but that's the kind of errors you should be able to solve by yourself by reading the error message, the traceback and the source code (learning to debug is required if you expect to do any coding).

Comment: There was another typo BTW (`for line in source` instead of `for line in fin`) - both fixed.

Comment: if I give a file name in fin, would it run for all the 1000 files? I am not able to understand what should I write in fin as open(source)

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make sense. `fin` is a `file` object, obtained from calling `open(source)`, where `source` is the absolute path to the file, built from `sourcedir`'s value and `filename`'s value. This code will iterate over all the files in `sourcedir`, skip the one that don't have a ".mdp" extension, and process the ones that have - and it will work (theoretically at least) regardless of how many .mdp files you have in `sourcedir`.

Comment: 'code'  
fin = open("/home/abc/xyz/mdp/md_1.mdp")
fout = open("/home/abc/xyz/mdb/md_1.mdp", "w")
could you please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: May I suggest that you read my example code line by line and try to understand what each line is doing (refering to the doc etc), then trace code execution (using [the debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to check what _actually_ happens ?

Comment: Also note that - __based on your original code snippet__ - my code writes the processed files in another directory (which is safer than trying to update a file in place anwyay).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to edit all files that are located in the mdp folder you could do something like this.

```
import os

dir = "/home/abc/xyz/mdp/"
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    with open(dir + filename, "r+") as file:
        text = file.read()
        text = text.replace("dt = 0.001", "dt = -0.001")
        file.seek(0)
        file.write(text)
        file.truncate()
```

This will go through every file and change it using str.replace().

If there are other files in the mdp folder that you do not want to edit, you could use and if-statement to check for the correct file name. Add something like this to encase the *with open* statement.

```
if filename.startswith("md_")
```

Comment: Overwriting the file in-place is unsafe - if anything goes wrong, you'll loose the original data. Better to write to a temporary file and then replace the original with the new one. Also, reading the whole file in memory can lead to MemoryError, better to work line by line (files are iterable).

Comment: Also note that in the OP's example, the processed file is actually written to another directory...